# How to do page wise subtotal in google spread sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I am in need of creating pagewise subtotal (page wise running total) in a google spread sheet.  This mean in each page (Letter-size) I need to sum a field and display. I see that spread sheet puts header & page numbers in each page. Is there a way that I can have this value too. After looking at the documentations and search I found the Spread Sheet doesn't have page break. Also tried to calculate the row heights and break the page by adding my sum and page numbers. That is not always reliable and messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noticed, Google Spreadsheets don't know anything about pages... Pages are created at export / printing time which is 'too late' for what you need to do.

The closest solution I can imagine would be to export a number of rows + the subtotal as a table into a Google document, the latter having page numbers, footers and headers to customize their layout in a proper way.

You will loose the spreadsheet features on your way but I don't know if that would be an issue for you.

You'll also loose part of the formatting (if you added some in the SS) but that should be more or less re-doable from within the text document.